# Not able to assign a TMyClass object to a variable of its base interface type

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface, variable-assignment, delphi-xe2

Why I cannot assign a class to a variable of its base interface type.

Consider we have the following:

```
IInt1 = interface
  procedure Test1;
end;

IInt2 = interface(IInt1)
  procedure Test2;
end;

TCustomClass = class(TInterfacedObject)
end;

TMyClass = class(TCustomClass, IInt2)
  procedure Test1;
  procedure Test2;
end;

var
  Obj: IInt1;
begin
  Obj := TMyClass.Create; // <!-- E2010 Incompatible types: 'IInt1' and 'TMyClass'
  ...
end;


E2010 Incompatible types: 'IInt1' and 'TMyClass'
```

Is this a bug in the compiler or simply not an allowed action. Can this be worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `IInt1` in the list of implemented interfaces in your declaration:

```
TMyClass = class(TCustomClass, IInt1, IInt2)
end;
```

Comment: In addition to that: Interface-inheritance is only for the interface. The class must specify explicitly what interfaces it implements. This has to do with the way, different interface versions (that derive from each other) are queried.

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors above, as follows:

1. The class declarations must contain all members required by the interface. TMyClass must therefore have procedures Test1 and Test2 defined.
2. Interfaces must have a GUID, as shown in the code below. Place your cursor where you want the GUID to appear, and press CTRL-SHIFT-G to get the IDE to create this for you.
3. When you assign the new class, you need to use the AS keyword for the typecast.

Your snippet of code, therefore, should look like this

```
IInt1 = interface
  ['{218BE5BB-0784-4E4A-923C-F1F1E116F38B}']
  procedure Test1;
end;

IInt2 = interface(IInt1)
  ['{635D00B2-AC59-43A9-A7DB-660F53EBCDD8}']
  procedure Test2;
end;

TCustomClass = class(TInterfacedObject)
private
  procedure Test1;
end;

TMyClass = class(TCustomClass, IInt2)
private
  procedure Test2;
end;

...

var
  Obj: IInt1;
begin
  Obj := TMyClass.Create AS IInt1;
  ...
```

Comment: Interfaces don't need a GUID. It is only required if you want to use the QueryInterface method directly or indirectly (`Supports`), or if you want a COM interface. So usually Interface have a GUID but it is not required. Furthermore the AS-operator is not necessary. The compiler knows enough to do the "type-cast" correctly.